# Use Docker on a systemd disabled VM

Tags: sudo, virtualization, systemd, services, docker

I am provided by a VM running Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS which has systemd disabled.

I have root access on it.

I am trying to run docker on it which is installed but I get error
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I cannot run `systemctl` as I get error
`System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.`

I ran the command `sudo service --status-all` and amongst the listed services Docker's service was not found.

Is there a way I can user docker here?

Comment: I think the correct answer to your question is no.

Comment: If not systemd, exactly which `init`  are you using? sysvinit? Upstart? Something else? And why?

Comment: @user535733 It's using ```sys-v```. I have no control over it. As I said I am provided with the VM.

Comment: So your question really seems to be "*How do I control services (including Docker) using sysvinit instead of systemd?*"

Comment: @user535733 I don't really know, I don't have that deep knowledge of linux. For now I just want a way to run docker.

Comment: You would need to consult the System V documentation for this. Since Ubuntu uses systemd as default init, you're probably better helped on [unix.se].